# Проблемы с виджетом QTextBrowser

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, qtextedit, qtextbrowser

Не работает `QTextBrowser`, в него просто напросто нельзя вставить текст?

---

Макет:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_newperson(object):
    def setupUi(self, newperson):
        newperson.setObjectName("newperson")
        newperson.resize(600, 600)
        newperson.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(600, 600))
        newperson.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(600, 600))
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(newperson)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 62, 301, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.name = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(newperson)
        self.name.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(320, 70, 231, 20))
        self.name.setObjectName("name")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(newperson)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 10, 401, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(newperson)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 130, 241, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.aboutpersontext = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(newperson)
        self.aboutpersontext.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 171, 501, 241))
        self.aboutpersontext.setObjectName("aboutpersontext")
        self.image = QtWidgets.QPushButton(newperson)
        self.image.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 500, 271, 51))
        self.image.setObjectName("image")
        self.makeperson = QtWidgets.QPushButton(newperson)
        self.makeperson.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 420, 131, 51))
        self.makeperson.setObjectName("makeperson")
        self.preview = QtWidgets.QPushButton(newperson)
        self.preview.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(410, 420, 161, 51))
        self.preview.setObjectName("preview")
        self.result = QtWidgets.QLabel(newperson)
        self.result.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 570, 391, 20))
        self.result.setText("")
        self.result.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.result.setObjectName("result")
        self.image_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(newperson)
        self.image_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(300, 500, 271, 51))
        self.image_2.setObjectName("image_2")

        self.retranslateUi(newperson)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(newperson)

    def retranslateUi(self, newperson):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        newperson.setWindowTitle(_translate("newperson", "Form"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("newperson", "Имя исторической личности:"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("newperson", "Создание новой исторической личности"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("newperson", "Введите его описание:"))
        self.image.setText(_translate("newperson", "Добавить картинку главную картинку"))
        self.makeperson.setText(_translate("newperson", "Добавить персонажа"))
        self.preview.setText(_translate("newperson", "Посмотреть текст"))
        self.image_2.setText(_translate("newperson", "Добавить картинки фантомов"))
```

**main.py**:

```
class NewPerson(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_newperson()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowTitle("Создание нового персонажа")
        self.name = ""
        self.text = ""
        self.FaceOfPerson = ""
        self.FacesOfPerson = ""
# События нажатия на кнопки
        self.ui.image.clicked.connect(self.ChoiceImage)
        self.ui.makeperson.clicked.connect(self.MakeNewPerson)
        self.ui.preview.clicked.connect(self.Preview)
        self.ui.image_2.clicked.connect(self.ChoiceImages)
# Подключаем текстовые поля
        self.ui.name.textChanged.connect(self.NewPersonName)
        self.ui.aboutpersontext.textChanged.connect(self.NewPersonAboutText)


# ТЕКСТОВОЕ ПОЛЕ "НОВОЕ ИМЯ"
    def NewPersonName(self, name):
        self.name = name

# ТЕКСТОВОЕ ПОЛЕ "НОВОЕ ОПИСАНИЕ"
    def NewPersonAboutText(self):
        self.text = self.ui.aboutpersontext.toPlainText()

# ФУНКЦИЯ Загрузки изображения
    def ChoiceImage(self):
        self.FaceOfPerson = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Выберите картинку с лицом исторической личности", None, "Image (*.png *.jpg)")[0]

        print(self.FaceOfPerson)

# ФУНКЦИЯ Загрузки изображения фантомов
    def ChoiceImages(self):
        self.FacesOfPerson = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames(self, "Выберите картинку с лицами фантомов", None, "*.png *.jpg")
        print(self.FacesOfPerson[0][1])

# ФУНКЦИЯ Открытия окна Предварительного просмотра
    def Preview(self):
        self.preview = DescriptionPersonPreview()
        self.preview.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Класс QTextBrowser предоставляет богатый текстовый браузер с гипертекстовой навигацией. Этот класс расширяет QTextEdit (в режиме `только для чтения`), добавляя некоторые функции навигации, чтобы пользователи могли следить за ссылками в гипертекстовых документах.

`Если вы хотите предоставить своим пользователям редактируемый текстовый редактор, используйте QTextEdit.`

Если вы хотите, чтобы текстовый браузер без гипертекстовой навигации использовал QTextEdit, и используйте QTextEdit :: setReadOnly (), чтобы отключить редактирование. Если вам просто нужно отобразить небольшой фрагмент богатого текста, используйте QLabel.